# Fullscreen button glitch

Tags: mediaelement.js

I, as well as several others have [an issue](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1637) regarding mediaelement.js and YouTube...specifically, the fullscreen function. It simply doesn't work. I even created a new button and it did not work.

It's a problem with FireFox 44, not Chrome or even IE/Edge, surprisingly. And it only occurs when I use YouTube with HTML5 and not flash. Others have problems with mobile also.

I suspect the [enterfullscreen()](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=enterFullScreen) function to be the culprit here, somehow... help if you can.

```
player.enterFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have a new development: since my CSS sets the video to 100%, it thinks it's in full-screen mode already. I ran a test; I changed it to 99.999% and viola -- the fullscreen works.